# Method closure not seeming to work in therubyracer

Tags: ruby, v8, therubyracer

Once I store a method in a V8::Context, all subsequent instances of that method stored in any context under any name behave like the initial one (i.e. as if the original instance had been stored again).

I tried to isolate/demonstrate the problem with the following:

```
require 'V8'

class TestClass
  def test_method
    self.inspect
  end
end

(1..2).each do |cxt_i|
  cxt = V8::Context.new
  [:test_method, :test_method2].each_with_index do |method_name, method_i|
    method = TestClass.new.method(:test_method)
    cxt[method_name.to_s] = method
    script = method_name.to_s+'()'
    puts "Context #{cxt_i}, method #{method_i+1} result is #{method.call}, V8 returns #{cxt.eval(script)}"
  end
end
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Context 1, method 1 result is #<TestClass:0x007fce2419cdb0>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007fce2419cdb0>
Context 1, method 2 result is #<TestClass:0x007fce2419b780>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007fce2419cdb0>
Context 2, method 1 result is #<TestClass:0x007fce2419abc8>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007fce2419cdb0>
Context 2, method 2 result is #<TestClass:0x007fce24199a98>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007fce2419cdb0>
```

Comment: I'm not getting that, my "V8 returns" are different in for contexts 1 and 2 (but the same within contexts).

Comment: @mu is too short: I don't understand your comment. If you mean you are getting different results than I am, can you share your code and your output?

Comment: Same code as you have. I get V8 returns values like `A`, `A`, `B`, `B` where yours is like `A`, `A`, `A`, `A`. Still not quite what you're expecting but closer.

Comment: @mu is too short: Thanks for the response.  Mind sharing your version information?  Mine is:libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86_64-darwin-12),  ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]  (Sorry couldn't get indentation to work in this comment.)

Comment: I just tried again with Ruby 2.0.0 and libv8-3.11.8.17, got the same results you did. The first one I did was 1.9.2 and libv8-3.3.10.4. Ah, the joys of upgrading.

Comment: Thanks. I've included this information on the associated therubyracer github issue (#260). FYI, I was hoping for A, B, C, D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weak reference issue.  By inserting a `GC.start` inside the inner loop, we force the weak references in the V8 context to be garbage collected.  Slows it down immensely though.

```
require 'v8'

class TestClass
  def test_method
    self.inspect
  end
end

(1..2).each do |cxt_i|
  cxt = V8::Context.new
  [:test_method, :test_method2].each_with_index do |method_name, method_i|
    method = TestClass.new.method(:test_method)
    cxt[method_name.to_s] = method
    script = method_name.to_s+'()'
    puts "Context #{cxt_i}, method #{method_i+1} result is #{method.call}, V8 returns #{cxt.eval(script)}"
    GC.start # <<<<=========
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Context 1, method 1 result is #<TestClass:0x007f8f13a26cd8>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007f8f13a26cd8>
Context 1, method 2 result is #<TestClass:0x007f8f135cca48>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007f8f135cca48>
Context 2, method 1 result is #<TestClass:0x007f8f135ceac8>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007f8f135ceac8>
Context 2, method 2 result is #<TestClass:0x007f8f135cdbf0>, V8 returns #<TestClass:0x007f8f135cdbf0>
```

ruby -v is `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]`, libv8 is `3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux`

Comment: Thanks, Matty. Not sure what to do with this information, but I appreciate the investigative work. I'm going to award you the bounty with the understanding that I can always shift it in case something better comes along. This is my first bounty award and my understanding is that I "use it or lose it". ;-)

Comment: Just had a long exchange on meta about bounty awarding. Turns out I can't move a bounty once assigned, but that there's a 24-hour grace period after the 7 days ends. In light of this, I'm going to leave the bounty unawarded for now, but will make sure I deal with it during the grace period assuming it's not really resolved before then.

Comment: If a better answer/workaround comes along we will all benefit.

Comment: This issue on github (#260) just closed as duplicate of https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/176 on assumption that this is indeed WeakRef problem. Recommended upgrading to 2.0

Comment: Ooops, just realized that you guys *reproduced it* on 2.0.  Made comment to that effect on github.